# How to set the open graph default image without access to <head>

Tags: html, facebook, meta-tags

I have a website on which I can modify/add html, PHP, and JS code on the page but I do not have access to the `<head></head>` section.

How can I set a default image for open graph so that it shows correctly when the page is being shared on Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

The linter (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) only likes to see the og: tags in the  section of the HTML.

> "You have  tags ouside of your . This is either because
>   your  was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or
>   you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either
>   way you need to fix it before the tags are usable."

I've even tried to put them into the DOM of the HEAD programmatically using javascript, but the linter doesn't appear to run the script.  It appears to be looking in the originally downloaded HTML.  So my advice is to look around for a better hosting solution.  Try GoDaddy.com for some awesome pricing on hosting packages.  You will need to gain access to the HEAD section and if you control the files, you'll be better off  :)

Comment: I am using commercial software for this particular site. They host it. No other options if I want to use their system. So I'm a bit stuck with them for now.

I also considered DOM manipulation through JS. Thanks for saving me time going that route.

Comment: Contact the manufacturer of the software and see if they can assist you.

Comment: yeah, they can. For a fat fee. That's why I am researching alternatives.

Comment: I would suggest posting the software name you're using so if anyone knows of some loopholes  ;)